# What does the "." in "docker run <image> . " do?

Tags: docker

I have 2 commands:

`docker run -d -p 5000:8080 ${image_name} .`

and

`docker run -d -p 5000:8080 ${image_name}`

The only difference between these two commands is the period at the end. What is the purpose of the period? I understand that it signifies the current directory, but what is its use in a command like this?

Answer (score 2):

Arguments after the image name are passed to the image's entrypoint, so it depends on the default `ENTRYPOINT` of the image. Often, the entrypoint is bash, so running

```
docker run -d -p 5000:8080 ${image_name} .
```

Is like running `bash .`.

The fact that you are publishing ports in your `docker run` command makes me think that the image runs a server. Let's say the entrypoint of your image is `python server.py`. Then the command

```
docker run -d -p 5000:8080 ${image_name} .
```

is akin to running `python server.py .`

and the command

```
docker run -d -p 5000:8080 ${image_name}
```

is akin to running `python server.py` (note the absence of the dot).